# Equivalent <transmission> or <actuator> tags in SDF (compared to URDF)

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Does anyone know what Gazebo 1.2 does with the information in  or  tags?  Perhaps using plugins?  I know I can, for instance, use a model plugin to set one joint angle to be equivalent to another joint angle in the OnUpdate() function, but this seems to screw with the physics (and generally be an inelegant hack).

Has anyone had any luck loading the old pr2 gripper into new Gazebo?  May be you can point me to an example of how to implement actuator or transmission models? I guess what I'm really interested in is a more elegant way to access the physics engine via a plugin to write my own transmissions like the ones used by pr2, or at least get theirs to work within a new Gazebo model.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/321/equivalent-%3Ctransmission%3E-or-%3Cactuator%3E-tags-in-sdf-(compared-to-urdf)/) by [Gwen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/52/gwen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-05-27**:
hey. so did u figure out how to attach the pr2 controller to the robot in sdf format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Gwen,

The transmission and actuator tags are used by the [`pr2_mechanism_model` package](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism_model).  Upstream to that, `pr2_mechanism_model` is loaded through the [`gazebo_ros_controller_manager` plugin](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_gazebo_plugins).  I've tried to explain it a little bit in the [header file copied over to drcsim](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/6ffc0e511d6aca66f3f2d966a85cb667db222329/plugins/ros/gazebo_ros_controller_manager.h?at=default).

If you want to see the pr2 gripper in action in the new gazebo, try it out in the groovy release of [pr2_simulator](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator) by simulating the entire PR2.  Otherwise, with a little bit of work, you might be able to get a working gripper by itself by stripping out the rest of the robot.

The different types of transmissions are implemented [here](https://kforge.ros.org/pr2mechanism/hg/file/5c563f56993c/pr2_mechanism_model/src).

Hope this helps.
John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-07-23**:
Checkout the new ros_control: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ros_control

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2016-02-16**:
This is an update to an old thread, as of today (Feb 16, 2016) there is no native transmission or actuator tags in SDF. Some beginning discussions on how to generalize actuators/transmission into SDF be found here https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_design/src/090bd9e7997523a97002ca55b2ac253b612845d6/transmission/transmission.md?fileviewer=file-view-default , inputs welcome.